# asynchronous image loader in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Does anyone know any good library/tutorial that can do asynchronous image loading for a cell in UITableView? I am looking for a method that doesn't involve too much code changing in my current code and easy to integrate to a regular synchronous UITableView.

Comment: You could refer to proxy design pattern....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try looking into [Three20](http://three20.info/)

An open source library written by the guy who wrote the official "Facebook" app for iOS.
Moreover, the code of the facebook app is based on that library.

Comment: Yes, TTImageView does a good job on async image loading - used it for many projects, always worked very well. Though I think that Three20 is overengineered and poorly documented.

Comment: So Three20 does the asynchronous automatically?

Comment: @adit - yes, TTImageView (part of Three20) does that.

Comment: but then I'll have to redo every class that I have because I am currently having something working in UITableViewController

Comment: So use the TTTableViewController which is Internet-Aware and automatically load the content of the table in the background, and fill the table when data comes in.

Comment: @adit, just stick to your UITableViewController implementation an replace your UIImageView's with TTImageView -> done!

Comment: does it cache the image as well Till?

Comment: Sounds great! I am gonna use it for sure! :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you rather do it by yourself, read [MHLazyTableImages](http://www.hollance.com/2011/03/mhlazytableimages-efficiently-load-images-for-large-tables/), it comes with a github project. It's an adaptation of Apple's LazyTableImages. Or you can use [HJCache](http://www.markj.net/hjcache-iphone-image-cache/).

Answer (score 1):

Fully-Loaded is another one which is pretty simple. It's more a generic image view loaded which you can use in custom table view cells.

https://github.com/foursquare/fully-loaded

Answer (score 0):

I quite like `SDWebImage`, which is an asynchronous image downloader with cache support with an `UIImageView` category.

https://github.com/brendanlim/SDWebImage